# Dynamic equation for the geometrodynamic field momentum in ADM formalism

Tags: general-relativity, adm-formalism

I'm currently working through MTW's Gravitation and I've reached Chapter 21. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to reproduce Equation 21.115 and have managed to produce 5 out of the six terms in the equation. Getting to the sixth term, albeit using the processes which have worked successfully so far, is just not happening. No-one on Physics Forum (I post under TerryW) is able to help. Is there anyone in Stack Exchange who is knowledgeable about the ADM formalism and is willing to try and give me a bit of assistance?

Here is Eq 21.115. The term underlined is the only one I can't reproduce. My workings on the other terms did produce four additional terms but two cancelled out and I thought that maybe other cancellations would arise from the working out of the final term. BTW I am pretty sure equations 21.116 and 21.117 are wrong!

[image: MTW 21.115]

Regards

TerryW

Comment: Welcome to the Physics StackExchange ! Could you please also put eq.(21.115) in the post? Thanks (If you don't know Mathjax, it's very similar to Latex).

Comment: Could you please reproduce equation (21.115) with all terms and  underline what actually you can't reproduce?

Comment: *six terms in the equation* I see *eight* terms, if you count parenthesized sums as one term.

Comment: I've underlined the bit I can't get to.